# create label on table view after loading data from json

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am making an inbox module in my app. I want to ask that i want to create a label programaticaly in UITableView after laoding data from Json. through which we click and get more data? How it can be done? Example like in facebook, we click on messages and by moving down we click on load more messages ??? on load more message label i ahve to send another call to load more message.

Comment: Are you referring to infinite scrolling of a tableview?

Comment: yes.. i am getting 25 records from my server .. i want to create a label after getting that 25 records,to load more records.

Comment: maam just grab data from Web Service and retrn the count in numberofrowinindexpath it will load basis of how many records u have.

Comment: if u r not getting my point give me ur email id i will send u demo project.

Comment: saba_shiraz@yahoo.com u can plz send here

Comment: and what about other records ... ??  means want to show a label in table view after loading data from server and on clickng on that label i will show more messages or records ??? Did u get my point ?

Comment: Have you tried anything ? . I think your approach is wrong. Please design a tableview cell, after parse the value objects added  to an array. The number of rows in table should be the array count. Then reload the tableView. This is a basic concept of tableView. Please study basics first.

Comment: i understand.. i had done... my question is when records are displayed on table view which are coming from server i have to add a label on which i click and load more records on the same table view.. i just want to ask how to make that label or button or whatever ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so you're gonna have to hack this all together. This is the usual approach to get a **"Load more data"** `cell` on your uitableview

Methods Needed

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return dataRows+1;
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 

    //after setting tableviewcell

    if(indexPath.row==dataRows){

    cell.textLabel.text=@"Load More Rows";
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   if(indexPath.row==dataRows){
      //there you can write code to get next rows
   }
}
```

Ok this is where the hacking will have to begin. Look at this [CODE](http://jslim.net/blog/2014/04/01/infinite-scroll-using-on-uitableview/).

The method that seems to be most important is

`- (void)reloadTableView:(int)startingRow`

Answer (score 0):

For that you can set as a button.If you click that button in tableview,you can get more data or else you can get data step by step like ten by ten data.

Create Custom Cell and Set the Button in Custom Cell also give name as `btnLoadMore`

In header file

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController {
    int loadMoreTableInt;
    int paginationInt; 
}
```

In .m file

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      loadMoreTableInt = 0;
      paginationInt = 1;    
 }


 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

      customCell *cell=(customCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Reuse"];

      NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customCell" owner:self options:nil];

      if(cell == nil) {

         cell=[nib objectAtIndex:0];

      }

     if(loadMoreTableInt-1> indexPath.row) {

        cell.labelName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[modelRoot.arrayName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


     } else {

        if(cell == nil) {
           cell=[nib objectAtIndex:1];
        }

        [cell.btnLoadMore setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Load More "] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        cell.btnLoadMore.tag=indexPath.row;

        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        [cell.btnSeeMorebtnLoadMore addTarget:self action:@selector(loadmoreButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

  }
```

In loadmoreButtonAction give the code like this

```
 -(void)loadmoreButtonAction:(id)sender {

     @try {
         UIButton *btn=(id)sender;

         paginationInt=paginationInt+1;
         [tableview reloadData];

         CGPoint point;
         point.x=40;
         point.y=btn.tag*53;

         NSIndexPath *path = [tableview indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
         [tableview scrollToRowAtIndexPath:path atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];

        }@catch (NSException *exception) {

      }
 }
```

Comment: thax i will check nd let you know :)